# PHP array sum key before

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, key

I've been trying to work with my array on a specific way but with no success. I've tried many different examples I could find here but no one helped me.

The `$SelectDiaSPReceita` prints thousands of results like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Origem] => VDC
        [Destino] => GRU
        [DataHoraVenda] => 2015-09-01 00:02:00.000
        [TotalEmissao] => 867.6800
    )
```

...

```
$arrayDiaSP = array();
foreach ($SelectDiaSPReceita as $value) {
    $hora = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 11, -10);
    $dia = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 8, -13);
    $mes = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 5, -16);
    $ano = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 0, -19);

    if(isset($arrayDiaSP[$hora])):
        $arrayDiaSP[$hora]['BilhetesVendidos']++;
        $arrayDiaSP[$hora]['TarifaTotal'] += $value['TotalEmissao'];
    else:
        $arrayDiaSP[$hora] = array( "Dia" => $dia, "Mes" => $mes, "Ano" => $ano, "Hora" => $hora, "BilhetesVendidos" => 1, "TarifaTotal" => number_format($value['TotalEmissao'], 2) );
    endif;
}
```

This is the array I made and it prints something like:

```
[00] => Array
    (
        [Dia] => 01
        [Mes] => 09
        [Ano] => 2015
        [Hora] => 00
        [BilhetesVendidos] => 81
        [TarifaTotal] => 20285.77
    )

[01] => Array
    (
        [Dia] => 01
        [Mes] => 09
        [Ano] => 2015
        [Hora] => 01
        [BilhetesVendidos] => 27
        [TarifaTotal] => 6733.52
    )

[02] => Array
    (
        [Dia] => 01
        [Mes] => 09
        [Ano] => 2015
        [Hora] => 02
        [BilhetesVendidos] => 11
        [TarifaTotal] => 4088.1
    )
```

until...

```
[23] => Array
    (
        [Dia] => 01
        [Mes] => 09
        [Ano] => 2015
        [Hora] => 23
        [BilhetesVendidos] => 80
        [TarifaTotal] => 23730.35
    )
```

Each key represents an hour of the day. What I'm trying to do is to sum the `BilhetesVendidos` and `TarifaTotal` from the current key to the key before. Eg.:

```
[00] => Array
    (
        [Dia] => 01
        [Mes] => 09
        [Ano] => 2015
        [Hora] => 00
        [BilhetesVendidos] => 81
        [TarifaTotal] => 20285.77
    )

[01] => Array
    (
        [Dia] => 01
        [Mes] => 09
        [Ano] => 2015
        [Hora] => 01
        [BilhetesVendidos] => 108
        [TarifaTotal] => 27019.29
    )

[02] => Array
    (
        [Dia] => 01
        [Mes] => 09
        [Ano] => 2015
        [Hora] => 02
        [BilhetesVendidos] => 119
        [TarifaTotal] => 31107,39
    )
```

And on and on.. until the last key. Basically it means:

```
key 00 = key 00
key 01 = key 00 + key 01
key 02 = key 01 + key 02
...
```

Any help, please?
Thank you!

Comment: It would be useful to see what the `$SelectDiaSPReceita` array looks like

Comment: Hi Riggs, I've just added it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$bilhetesVendidos = 0;
$tarifaTotal      = 0;

foreach ($arrayDiaSP as &$entry) {
    $bilhetesVendidos += $entry['BilhetesVendidos'];
    $tarifaTotal      += $entry['TarifaTotal'];

    $entry['BilhetesVendidos'] = $bilhetesVendidos;
    $entry['TarifaTotal']      = $tarifaTotal;
}
```

It sums up values and replaces every hour's `BilhetesVendidos` and `TarifaTotal` with the sum of all previous entries.

It'll need to be a different approach if you only want to sum up the current and previous values without affecting the subsequent entries.

Comment: Mmm... I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I've tried but it didn't work as I expected.

Comment: Could you give an example of the output for 3-4 entries in your array? When you say "sum from the current key to the key before", would the previous key at the point of summing up be a sum of all previous keys or would the value be what it was before processing the array? E.g. if the array was A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5 then in the first scenario you would end up with 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and in the second one with 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 (which is what my example does).

Comment: I have no words to express how happy you made me. I was trying in some way that didn't work, but now I got it and it works like a charm. Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hehe, de nada! The solution isn't really that difficult, is it if you simply use temporary variables. :)